# pvPortMalloc in multithreaded application

Tags: c, freertos

I'm running an application with several threads in TI-RTOS with CCS7.2, using their implementation of `pthread` `mutex`, `condition` and `thread`. 
They all use `pvPortMalloc` to allocate memory dynamically.

To keep my threads small, I'm dynamically allocating the larger memory chunks my threads are using with their `malloc` implementation, yet another wrapper around `pvPortMalloc`.

Among others, there are these two allocations:

```
/* thread A ***************************/
#define CONST_ARRAY_SIZE 4
typedef struct {
    uint16_t var1;
    uint8_t var2;
    uint32_t var3[CONST_ARRAY_SIZE];
    /* ... */
    /* sizeof(MyStruct) == 0x58 according to debugger */
} MyStruct;
MyStruct *p_myBuffer = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct)); // p_myBuffer = ucHeap + 0x40D0
/* thread B ***************************/
static pthread_mutex_t myMutex = NULL;
pthread_mutex_init(&myMutex); // myMutex = ucHeap + 0x4118 - why is this allowed?
```

The problem is obvious: as soon as `p_myBuffer` gets initialized, the properties in `myMutex` are overwritten. On the first `pthread_mutex_lock`, the mutex runs into `configASSERT` because the mutex's semaphore has become invalid.

Is there anything that can make `pvPortMalloc` "forget" some memory is still in use or forget about chunk sizes? **I wonder why the system allows allocation of mutex memory at that heap address and treats an address between `ucHeap + 0x40D0` and `ucHeap + 0x4128` as available.**

Is the heap management misinterpreting the array member and doesn't count all elements' sizes, but rather some pointer size? I've come across some strange interpretations of variables' `sizeof` with this toolchain.

From what I know about dynamic allocation, any buffer allocated from heap (I'm using heap4) should persist and remain blocked for further allocations across all threads. Those don't seem to do so - is there any way a heap-allocated memory block can silently go out of scope and get `free`d? I've debugged to the point where I can rule out an explicit `free`.

A possibly related issue I've come across was that sometimes sizeof doesn't work right:

```
uint8_t integerSize = sizeof(uint32_t); // integerSize yields 4
uint32_t sampleInteger;
integerSize = sizeof(sampleInteger); // integerSize yields 1
```

I'm not sure which POD type actually caused this behavior, but I remember it broke some buffer allocations, and it wasn't the usual array/pointer issue. Is there anything in particular that may cause this? Can the two issues be related? After all, if `sizeof` returns something too small, the malloc may cause a buffer overflow on full initialization.

Comment: FreeRTOS malloc implementation is very light-weight and you don't need to do one step more.

Comment: @tilz0R That's what I thought, but something seems to go wrong. Is there any way to mess up linkage such that the heap implementation's free block addresses may end up on the wrong thread stack, allowing for double use?

Comment: This happened only if you used your mamory wrong. Did you write memory outside your area? So, allocate 5 bytes and write up to 10bytes? Then you do corruption!

Comment: @tilz0R That's understood. Sadly, that can only be the case if TI-RTOS doesn't get its sizeofs right - see the example. I'll update the question with an example of the sizeof issue I've come across earlier. Maybe they can have the same root cause.

Comment: No! Malloc works ok, it aligns data automaticaly to (usually) 4 bytes. Implementation is not a problem, you usage is.

Comment: @tilz0R I know. That's why I would like to know what NOT to do (other than allocate less than needed, forget to free something after use or free the first chunk ever allocated - attempting to do so corrupts the heap4 version I'm using). Both allocations are successful, the breakpoint at `free` never triggers, but the allocated areas overlap.

Comment: `static pthread_mutex_t myMutex = NULL;` compiles without warning?

Comment: @AndrewHenle `pthread_mutex_t` resolves to a fallback handle type of `void *`, so yes. Also, `pthread_mutex_init(pthread_mutex_t *p_mutex)` contains the assignment `*p_mutex = pvPortMalloc(...)`.  `pthread_cond_init`, however, will dereference the parameter given, so the value must be given as a struct (`pthread_cond_t myCondition = { NULL };`is cool, though). The implementation is taken from SDK 1.60.

Comment: @starturtle Implementation is ok and works ok. Period. End of story. Problem is your usage of memory returned by malloc. Period. End of story.

Comment: @starturtle Well, that would explain the lack of `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALZER` in TI-RTOS - it's impossible to statically initialize a mutex if the underlying implementation of `pthread_mutex_t` is `void *`.  One way to check if your problem really is a broke `sizeof()` is to replace `MyStruct *p_myBuffer = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));` with `MyStruct *p_myBuffer = malloc(0x58);` or even `MyStruct *p_myBuffer = malloc(0x100);`.  If your problems disappear with the use of `malloc(0x58)`, that's pretty strong evidence that you're dealing with a buggy `sizeof()`, assuming that `0x58` size is accurate.